# Facebook Pay Dialog Not Calling Callback After Confirmation

Tags: java, facebook, credits

I have implemented a servlet in Java that handles the credits communications with Facebook (as per the API). I implemented the servlet to perform the same functionality as the example php code and following the guidelines in the API.

I send FB the id of the item and get a response with the method "payments_get_items". I respond correctly which creates a popup dialog asking for payment confirmation (with all the product data). When I click confirm, Facebook does not make another call to my servlet but instead tells me my app is not responding. I find this strange and have found no way to resolve this issue.

Below is the JSON i am sending back to FB when i am asked to perform "payments_get_items". image_URL is an actual URL which has works. Am i possibly missing something in my response?

{"content":[{"description":"test","image_url":image_URL,"item_id":"siPremiumShotgun","price":2,"product_url":image_URL,"title":"Premium Shotgun"}],"method":"payments_get_items"}

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Lario Did you find any solution for above i m also facing same problem.. Please help .. i really appreciate your help thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your SSL is a non-free version really authentic SSL cert.

Comment: Hi DMCS my is SSL Authentic.. did you know other solution for this